# Airflow throw an error on filling up the DagBag while "airflow resetdb", before tables created

Tags: airflow

I am using Airflow to build dags dynamically.
The dag builder uses "variable" to get and set values.

When I am running "airflow resetdb", Airflow throw an error: "(psycopg2.ProgrammingError) relation "variable" does not exist".

I see that Airflow Filling up the DagBag while "airflow resetdb" and before the tables created.

Why airflow running "Filling up the DagBag", while "airflow resetdb"?

Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Run `airflow upgradedb`. This would create all the missing tables for you.

Comment: the tables exist, the problem is that when I am running "airflow resetdb" it first drop the tables and then recreate them. But before the recreation of tables, it filling up the DagBag (not sure why).

Comment: Though it's late to respond to the issue, let me add a step here which might help others. First, we need to delete all the files present in the dags folder and then run the ```airflow resetdb``` command. The command will run without any errors.